# SQL SPLIT a string by means of delimiters but reporting NULL when there is missing values

Tags: sql, string, split, google-bigquery

I am working with BigQuery and I want to split this following kind of string:
;%20kostenlos%20%20online%20%20game;b;g;177393617893;
into 5 different values. The code I am using is this following:

```
   FROM (select *, FIRST(SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')) part1,
   NTH(2, SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')) part2,
   NTH(3, SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')) part3,
   NTH(4, SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')) part4,
   NTH(5, SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')) part5
```

What I am getting stuck into is this: for some strings, some values are missing, and when it happens, that code is not reporting NULL for that piece, but the following piece of string. As instance:

```
;%20kostenlos%20%20online%20%20game;b;;177393617893;
```

then it will be splitted this way:

```
   part 1 = %20kostenlos%20%20online%20%20game
   part 2 = b
   part 3 = 177393617893 (instead of NULL)
   part 4 = blank (instead of 177393617893)
   part 5 = blank (and that's fine)
```

How to avoid that?

Comment: Edit your question and provide an example *in the question* of what you mean.

Comment: i edited the question providing an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
#legacySQL
SELECT *, 
FIRST(SPLIT(REPLACE(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';;', '; ;'), ';')) part1,
NTH(2, SPLIT(REPLACE(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';;', '; ;'), ';')) part2,
NTH(3, SPLIT(REPLACE(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';;', '; ;'), ';')) part3,
NTH(4, SPLIT(REPLACE(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';;', '; ;'), ';')) part4,
NTH(5, SPLIT(REPLACE(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';;', '; ;'), ';')) part5
FROM clicks_table
```

> for BigQuery StandardSQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS part1,
  SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS part2,
  SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS part3,
  SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS part4,
  SPLIT(clicks_table.affiliate_sub5, ';')[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] AS part5
FROM  clicks_table
```